# Pass controller action to a component in EmberJS returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a controller in EmberJS with an action, inside the route template I'm calling a component, and passing the controller's action to the component as a parameter. Just like documentation says in [EmberJS 2.20 Triggering changes with actions](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/)
When I'm trying to call the `"parent"` action inside the component, the return is undefined, but if I throw on console, `"this"` element and inspect its attr, the function is there.
**Controller js code:**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  firstName:'',
  lastName:'',
  actions: {
    addAlumn (){
      this.store.createRecord('alumn',{
        firstName : this.get('firstName'),
        lastName : this.get('lastName')
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**Route hbs template:**

```
{{#validated-form submit=(action 'addAlumn') saveBtn=true }} ... {{/validated-form}}
```

**Validated-form hbs template**

```
{{yield}}
{{#if saveBtn}}
<a href="#" class="btn primary save"{{action "validateAndSubmit"}}>Add <span class="icon-check"></span></a>
{{/if}}
```

**Validate-form js code**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions : {
    validateAndSubmit(){
      console.log('validate');
      console.log(this);
      console.log(this.get('submit')());
    }
  }
});
```

As I said, the results on console are:

```
> validate
> Class {__ember1449505261281: "ember496", __ember_meta__: Meta, parentView: Class, HAS_BLOCK [id=__ember1449505261281400801945202]: true, _targetObject: Class…}
> undefined
```

Any clues on why this is not triggering the event? Maybe is because the guide example is working just with components and I'm using a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `componentInstance.sendAction` please:

```
validateAndSubmit() {
  console.log('validate');
  this.sendAction('submit');
}
```

[Working demo.](https://ember-twiddle.com/273fa15701dec2504162)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works seamlessly, but I don't get why my code wasn't working if it's what the guide says. Could you explain it briefly? Thanks again.

Comment: You need to put your action in correct controller. I updated my demo - https://ember-twiddle.com/273fa15701dec2504162 - and `this.get('submit')` gets logged correctly. See for yourself. That approach works fine.